# How do I get an Arduino GSM shield to send a test when a button is pressed?

Tags: mobile, while-loop, sms, arduino, gsm

This is the code I'm currently trying to use. the system will send the needed test without the button code attached. I have placed the commands for the button in the while loop but I'm unsure if this is correct. I want the system to initiate the GSM shield and hold itself in a loop waiting for a release (the button) to tell it to send the text. Any input would help me out. I could be totally wrong, so please let me know. I would rather not use AT commands. I am using an Arduino UNO and a spark fun GSM shield SM5100B

```
#include <GSM.h>

#define PINNUMBER ""
int ledPin = 13;
int inPin = 7;  
int val = 0; 

// initialize the library instance
GSM gsmAccess; // include a 'true' parameter for debug enabled
GSM_SMS sms;

// char array of the telephone number to send SMS
// change the number 1-212-555-1212 to a number
// you have access to
char remoteNumber[20]= "xxxxxxxxxxxx";  

// char array of the message
char txtMsg[200]="Test";

void setup()
{
  pinMode(ledPin, OUTPUT); 
  pinMode(inPin, INPUT); 
  // initialize serial communications
  Serial.begin(9600);

  Serial.println("SMS Messages Sender");

  // connection state
  boolean notConnected = true;

  // Start GSM shield
  // If your SIM has PIN, pass it as a parameter of begin() in quotes
  while(notConnected)
  {
    if(gsmAccess.begin(PINNUMBER)==GSM_READY)
      notConnected = false;
    else
    {
      Serial.println("Not connected");
      delay(1000);
    }
  }
  Serial.println("GSM initialized");
  val = digitalRead(inPin);  // read input value
  if (val == HIGH) {         // check if the input is HIGH (button released)
    digitalWrite(ledPin, LOW);  // turn LED OFF
  } else {
    digitalWrite(ledPin, HIGH); 
    sendSMS(); 
  }
}

void loop()
{
// nothing to see here
}

void sendSMS(){

  Serial.print("Message to mobile number: ");
  Serial.println(remoteNumber);

  // sms text
  Serial.println("SENDING");
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println("Message:");
  Serial.println(txtMsg);

  // send the message
  sms.beginSMS(remoteNumber);
  sms.print(txtMsg);
  sms.endSMS(); 
  Serial.println("\nCOMPLETE!\n");  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Probabily it is wrong, you only check if the button is pressed just after the initialization.
You should always check for button press, so you have to check during the loop(), also you need some debounce code, as clickong a button may cause many rapid HIGH - LOW state,  see http://arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/Debounce

pay attention to set right PINNUMBER ora your card will be blocked (instead of a while, try just one time)

Answer (score 0):

maybe library from http://www.gsmlib.org/download.html can help you? :)

Answer (score -2):

format of begin(pinnumber,restart,sync). in which restart and sync is by default true.
so make some changes. pass false in place of restart so that your gsm module wont restart and let sync as it is.
try it becoz it worked in my case...
begin(pinnumber,false)